# A problem related to Relation notation.

Tags: functions, relations

Consider number $2$ $and$ $3$. There is a relation between these numbers that later one (3) is just 1 greater then first one (2). I can represent this sentence like this: $3$ **R**  $2$, Where **R** mean "greater then" . Now there is another notation like (3,2) ∈ **R**. ***[Here in ordered pair first element is greater then second element].***
Here I having problem. In first notation **R** simply mean "greater then" but in second notation we are considering **R** to be a set. How  could "greater then"  be a set? 
Pardon me if this seems stupid. But I would be grateful if you consider explaining where I am doing mistake. Thanks

Comment: The observation "$3$ is greater than $2$" must somehow be caught in our mathematics. How do we do that?... By saying that $(3,2)\in R$ where $R$ denotes the set of order pairs $(n,m)$ that satisfy the condition "$n$ is greater than $m$". That is a very effective way and I am convinced that a better one cannot be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subsets of a set correspond with *properties*.

For instance if we look at $\mathbb Z$ then the fact that e.g. $5$ is a positive integer can be expressed by: $5\in\{n\in\mathbb Z\mid n>0\}$ showing that the property of "being positive" corresponds with the subset of positive elements.

> "How  could "greater then"  be a set?"

If it comes to *relations* then we are looking at properties of ordered pairs.

The statement that $3$ is greater than $2$ can be looked at as a property of ordered pair $(3,2)$.

Denoting this **property** by $P$ we then have the **set** $\{(n,m)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\mid P(n,m)\}$ and denoting this set with $R$ for $(n,m)\in\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z$ we have:$$P(n,m)\iff(n,m)\in R$$

So in this context $(3,2)\in R$ means exactly that $3$ is greater than $2$.

Further $3R2$ must be seen as nothing more or less than an abbreviation of $(3,2)\in R$.

Comment: Well, I must say this is very neat and ingenious answer. But I want to know how did you learn it? I am new to mathematics (beginner), if you tell me a book or something like that then it would be great. Thanks for answering by the way.

Comment: Glad to help. I would say that these things are learned by "doing mathematics" and also asking questions on e.g. this site. Sorry, but I cannot refer to any books.

Answer (score 1):

If your textbook (or whatever reference you are using) talks about "relations" it should have a **definition** of the word "relation".  What is that definition. A common one in math texts is "a relation on set X is a subset of XxX (the set of ordered pairs of elements of X)".  That is, the standard mathematical definition of "relation" **is** as a set! a has relation "R" to b if and only if (a, b) is in that set.